# Eclipse: adding resources to Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, runnable

I am trying to export an application I am building, but I have run into some trouble. It can't seem to load one of the resource files. The resource file is located in one of the packages in my src folder. I have tried all three of the options when exporting a Jar. I really hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your environment? Are you using an IDE and/or a tool like Maven? Some information about the project structure is nice too.

Comment: Can you write your piece of code that load the resource??

Comment: @EightBitBoy title said he was using Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails why don't you try using [FatJar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/)? Its an Eclipse plugin for building JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Project Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export` and make sure your resource is ticked.